# Rails tutorial Missing helper file helpers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, helper

I am at the beginning of the rails tutorial, building the blog.  I'm using Windows10.

I'm trying to get the homepage to say `hello world` instead of the default.  I added the code `root 'welcome#index'` to the `routes.rb` file.

Reloading the page, I get the following error:

> AbstractController::Helpers::MissingHelperError in
>   WelcomeController#index
>
> Missing helper file
>   helpers/c:/users/phil/desktop/blog/app/helpers/application_helper.rb_helper.rb
>
> Rails.root: c:/Users/Phil/desktop/blog
>
> app/controllers/application_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
>   app/controllers/welcome_controller.rb:1:in`'

I looked at other pages and they talked about uppercase and lowercase issues, and I noted that that Users and Phil is uppercase in the Rails.root method, but lowercase in the missing helper file helpers location description. I'm not sure if that's the problem, but even if it is I don't know how to fix it!

I am also having trouble interpreting the app/controllers, which I imagine points to the solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
application_helper.rb_helper.rb
```

Check this file, the name looks suspicious, maybe you changed it involuntarily. It should be `application_helper.rb`.

Comment: I thought that this looked strange as well.  So I played with it a bit before posting my question.  So what is telling the app to look for that file?  I couldn't figure out how to change that?  But check this out, the plot thickens!

Comment: Oops... anyway, so the plot thickens...

When I go to that file location, I find that my file is properly named :
c:/users/phil/desktop/blog/app/helpers/application_helper.rb

So before posting last night, I changed the file name to match the name in the error.  I changed it to application_helper.rb_helper.rb

Then I go and reload the page, and the error page adds a third _helper.rb!!:
Missing helper file helpers/c:/users/phil/desktop/blog/app/helpers/application_helper.rb_helper.rb_helper.rb